# Create single async webmethod on asp.net webforms to long polling

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a little project that I want to implement `long polling` in.  I do not want to use SignalR or any other third-party libraries for this.  I have a `ASP.NET WebForm` that I implement a simple web method, exposed through the asp.net page (decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute).

This is a very simple project and only this single method needs to be used in an async fashion so it isn't using threads from the request pool.  I'm not interested in third-party libraries that accomplish this, MVC Async Controllers, entire Async Webform page, etc...  I am just looking for a simple implementation to get this to work on a single method that will be requested via AJAX requests from the client.

So far I'm not sure how to approach it as most of the resources I have found out-right implement async for the entire project, which is **NOT** what I want.

Anyone have any ideas or resources on how I can accomplish this small thing?

Comment: Looking for the same thing myself.  So far it appears you'll want to call RegisterAsyncTask in your method, and set Page.AsyncMode.  If I get some working code soon, I'll post as an answer, until then hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: The 'small' thing you are asking about is not really very small. It's a major paradigm shift, which is why other frameworks have been created to do it. SignalR is now part of ASP.NET, so it's not a third party library any more. I would recommend using it rather than doing this yourself - you will be fighting against it as you are trying to do something with ASP.NET web forms that is not what it was designed for. It will probably be quicker, simpler and cleaner to use SignalR and leverage what's already there.

Answer (score 1):

There is an MSDN Sample that uses the ManualResetEvent class, a script manager control, and a webservice to implement long polling (they call it reverse ajax in the sample).

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETReverseAJAX-7a1f0c2b